# Which is grammatically correct? we're having rain or we've been having rain

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, present-tense

Can you believe all of this rain we've been having?

or

Can you believe all of this rain we are having?

Comment: Both are fine. Now, if you are asking because someone marked one of these sentences as wrong, you need to tell us, and you need to provide the context. 1. Was anything said before or after that sentence? 2. Had the rain just ended or was it being forecast again. 3. Was it still raining when the speaker uttered their phrase? 4. Is this taken from a multiple choice test? Is the option "both" also included?

Comment: I was given a set of sentences and they were all independent and I wondered if these two sentences will mean the same or not.

Answer (score 1):

`Can you believe all of this rain we've been having?`

This denotes you're pointing out to rains for quite a some time now (Duration)

---

`Can you believe all of this rain we are having?`

This denotes you're pointing out to rains for the current instance

---

Hope this helps